# Why serializing a QuerySet I iobtain a string?

Tags: python, django, serialization

I'm using a `js` function to obtain some data from my `django` models. Concretely, I want to obtain the last value from my sensors.

I'm doing the following,

```
from django.core import serializers
def getData(request):
    ctx = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        select = int(request.POST['Select'])

        last_val = DevData.objects.order_by('dev_id','-data_timestamp').distinct('dev_id')
        data = serializers.serialize('json', last_val)
        print(data)
        print('****************')
        print(data[0]) # I just obtain a "[" then is a string not a list
        ctx = {'Select':data}

    return JsonResponse(ctx)
```

My question is, why the output is a string? How can I convert it to a Json object and then pass it to my `js` function?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: You obtain a string, because a JSON, well, is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obtain a string, because JSON is a text format. You can for example use `json.loads` to convert it back to a list of dictionaries:

```
from json import loads as jsonloads
from django.core import serializers

def getData(request):
    ctx = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        select = int(request.POST['Select'])

        last_val = DevData.objects.order_by('dev_id','-data_timestamp').distinct('dev_id')
        data = jsonloads(serializers.serialize('json', last_val))
        ctx = {'Select':data}
    return JsonResponse(ctx)
```

The JSON serialization in Django is just a special `JsonEncoder` named [**`DjangoJSONEncoder`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/core/serializers/json.py#L76), that has some special cases for a `datetime` object, etc.

Comment: First of all, thanks!! Second, your `from json import jloads as jsonloads` fails, but with `from json import loads` it works. :)

Comment: @Lleims: sorry, that was a typo :). `import loads as jsonloads` should normally work.